# React Native - how to change keyboard punctuation/symbol

Tags: react-native, keyboard

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT0iG.png)

This is my current keyboard pad which is keyboardType="numeric". I want to change the symbol to '+' as I only want to allow my user to input either '+' or digits.

I've tried different keyboardType but could not find any method to modify the symbol. The only method I can think of is using normal keyboardType, then use regex to prevent user to input anything besides digits and '+'.

Please help if you know how to do it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not change the button on keyboard. You are right, you can use regex

```
^[0-9 +]+$
```

So in your case below code can be used

```
const [number, setNumber] = React.useState<string>('');

const onChangeText = (text:string)=>{
 setNumber(string.replace(/^[0-9 +]+$/g, ""))
}

<TextField onChangeText={onChangeText} />
```

Comment: Yeah I guess there is no way to change the keyboard button. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If it helped you can accept it and close the open question.